# Can I keep free games on my list when they are uninstalled?

Tags: steam

Is there a way to keep free games on the list just like paid games when I uninstall them? I want to keep my free games in the list so I know which ones I had when I reinstall my PC.

Answer (score 5):

**No, you cannot.**

Free to Play games (which are not installed) will only appear in your library if you own any DLCs or have early access to a particular game.  If you wish for a list of Free to Play games which you have previously played you will have to go through your games list through your profile.

[image: Games]

This list will include any Free to Play games you have previously installed, even those which you have not played yet.

[image: Games]

Answer (score 4):

I think not.

But you can remove them and then have it for download, but put in no download priority and it will be on the list.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, but only if you can get a steam key/license from another platform (e.g. a physical copy, Good Old Games, itch.io, the publishers website). When the game is registered like that it will stay in your account.